# Can I change code/values while in debugging mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate), is it possible to step through some code, and, if a variable is not correct (e.g. you want to get all records beginning with 'A' but there is none, so you want to try 'B' instead), is it possible to change the code while in debug mode, to do this (change variables while in debug mode)?

It is quite annoying to have to stop debugging, change a value, then debug again and see the result. It'd be much easier to do it all in debug mode, anyway.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the watch window just enter the statement you want executed. For example if you want to set the variable `prefix` to `"B"` then just type `prefix = "B"` and hit enter.

You may also change code while running, however there are a number of limitations to this feature. See Microsoft's Edit and Continue documentation for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c(v=vs.80).aspx.

Comment: also in the immediate window you could go: myVariable = "B"

Answer (score 1):

In the Solution Explorer view, right-click on each reference of References, choose Properties. In the Properties view, sign False to the field of Embed Interop Types. This works for me.
c